# Boolean operations in Python (notation in the docs)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not a novice programmer and I know what booleans are and how to use them. Trouble is, I can't quite understand what is implied in Python's documentation regarding boolean operations:

```
or_test  ::=  and_test | or_test "or" and_test
and_test ::=  not_test | and_test "and" not_test
not_test ::=  comparison | "not" not_test
```

What does all this recursion mean? Why should there be an "and_test" inside of an or_test? 
The same question about "not_test" in the description of and_test
The third line makes even less sense to me. 
Could anyone please guide me through these lines so that I can finally understand this somewhat unnecessarily recursive and tangled notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the larger [language grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) and in essence specifies the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

It means that `and` binds tighter than `or` does. Note that `or_test` does not **have** to contain `and`, it contains the `and_test` *rule*, which is constructed from *either* an `not_test` rule or `and_test "and" not_test`. `not_test` itself constructed in a similar manner, etc.

Also see the [*Notation* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation) of the reference documentation.

Comment: Do I get it right that this EBNF notation doesn't actually indicate the syntax of boolean operations but rather the order in which Python's interpreter evaluates expressions inside of a construction?

Comment: Well, it does *both*. The syntax for the AND boolean operation is spelled `and`, for example. Expression grammar rules are generally very simple; compare these with the rules for [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html).

Comment: Thank you, Martijn! You helped a lot.